# Adding header view to WKWebView ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

Has anyone managed to successfully add a header or footer view to a `WKWebView` `ScrollView`?

I'm currently trying to do this using the method described here for a `UIWebView` [Adding a header view to a UIWebView similar to Safari and Articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483028/adding-a-header-view-to-a-uiwebview-similar-to-safari-and-articles).

When this method is used in a `WKWebView` the content view `origin.y` is correctly changed but content is cut off at the bottom.

Using the scroll view content offset is also not possible as it breaks fixed positioned CSS elements in the web view.

Comment: Hi, I encountered same question. The existing answers are all about `UIWebView` and there is no solution for `WKWebview`. So I decide to place a bounty on this question.

Comment: can you provide any code or screenshot that satisfy your need?

Comment: You could insert it as an HTLM code after the webview loads

Comment: I have a working implementation that does this by just adding a view to the webview's scrollView, did you try that and it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

In webView Delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

add the following codebase,

```
mainWebViewObj.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerView.frame.size.height,0.0,headerView.frame.size.height,0.0);
mainWebViewObj.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

if(![headerView superview])
{
    [webView.scrollView addSubview:headerView];
    [webView.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:headerView];
}
[mainWebViewObj.scrollView setContentOffset:
 CGPointMake(0, -mainWebViewObj.scrollView.contentInset.top) animated:NO];
```

this worked perfect for me. Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that I think does as you describe.  It offsets the web content by setting `contentInset` on the `scrollView`, and by offsetting the header view frame by a negative amount:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    WKWebView*  _webView;

    UIView*     _headerView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview: _webView];

    [_webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]]];


    [_webView.scrollView setContentInset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)];

    _headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, -100, 375, 100)];
    _headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [_webView.scrollView addSubview: _headerView];
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    _webView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    CGRect f = _headerView.frame;
    f.size.width = _webView.bounds.size.width;
    _headerView.frame = f;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this suffers from the same problem mentioned in the question where using content offset breaks fixed positioned CSS elements in the web view.